# Typescript + mongodb : create index

Tags: mongodb, typescript

Hello I'm having trouble creating an index to delete automatically expired rows something like:

> db.eventlog.createIndex(   { created_at: 1 },   { expireAfterSeconds:
> 3600, partialFilterExpression: { state: 'TMP' } } );

my code:

```
export type PasswordRecoveryAttributes = {
  employee_id: string;
  email: string;
  token: string;
  used: boolean;
  expiration: Date;
  latitude: string;
  longitude: string;
};

const PasswordRecoverySchema = new Schema(
  {
    employee_id: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    used: {
      type: Boolean,
      trim: true,
      default: false,
      required: true,
    },
    expiration: {
      type: Date,
    },
    ip: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    latitude: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: false,
    },
    longitude: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    
  },
);
type PasswordRecoveryDoc = Document & PasswordRecoveryAttributes;
export interface PasswordRecoveryDocument extends PasswordRecoveryDoc {}
// For model
export interface PasswordRecoveryModel extends Model<PasswordRecoveryDocument> {}
export default mongoose.model<PasswordRecoveryDocument>(
  'PasswordRecovery',
  PasswordRecoverySchema,
);
```

connection:

```
(async () => {
  const mongoUserPass = mongoConfig.username
    ? `${mongoConfig.username}:${mongoConfig.password}@`
    : '';
  const connection = await mongoose.connect(
    `mongodb://${mongoUserPass}${mongoConfig.host}:${mongoConfig.port}/${mongoConfig.database}`,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    },
  );
})()
```

But I’m not able to imagine how to do this in typescript and
Mongo

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestions: It would help your work if your can think in terms of
> `Mongoose`, which was meant for this, it helps you in this task to *model* your objects for MongoDb

---

**To answer your question**:

```
class EmployeePassword  {
  ...
  @index(1, { unique: true, sparse: true, name: 'email_unique_index' }) email: string;
 
  @index() someId: number;
}
```

---

Now with Mongoose a [good example](https://know-thy-code.com/mongoose-schemas-models-typescript/):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const EmployeePassword = new Schema({
    employee_id: string;
 email: string;
 token: string;
 used: boolean;
 expiration: Date;
 latitude: string;
 longitude: string;
});
```